# Approximation of square integrable function with continuous periodic function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, approximation, riemann-integration

Let $f$ be a function from $(a,b)$ to $\mathbb R$, such that $f^2$ has finite improper Riemann integral on $(a,b)$. I know that, if $f$ is bounded, then for all $\varepsilon>0$ it is possible to find a uniformly continuous function $g : (a,b) \to \mathbb R$ such that: $$\lim_{x \to a^{+}} g(x) = \lim_{x \to b^{-}} g(x)$$
And:
$$\int_a^b (f(x)-g(x))^2 \mathrm{d}x < \varepsilon$$
My question is: does such a function $g$ also exist if $f$ is not bounded?

The proof I know for the bounded function case first shows that the convergence of the integral of $f^2$ implies the convergence of the integral of $|f|$, then uses the definition of Riemann integral to choose a suitable Riemann partition of $[a,b]$, and finally takes $g$ such that it is piecewise linear and its image in each $[x_{k-1}, x_{k}]$ is included in $[\min_{x \in [x_{k-1}, x_k]} f(x), \max_{x \in [x_{k-1}, x_k]} f(x)]$. With such a $g$, since the boundedness of $f$ allows us to pick a constant $M$, not dependent on $\varepsilon$, such that $|f(x)-g(x)|<2M$, we obtain:
$$\int_a^b (f(x)-g(x))^2 \mathbb{d}x \leq 2M \int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)| \mathrm{d}x <2M\varepsilon$$
However, if $f$ is not bounded, one can't so easily estimate the integral of $(f(x)-g(x))^2$ with that of $|f(x)-g(x)|$ (which can be easily made as little as we want in both cases).

Comment: What does the word "limited" mean? (Maybe a translation issue?)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @KennyWong whops, edited.

Comment: Could you please tell us how this question came about? Is this a homework exercise? Or this a hypothesis you came up with through experimentation?

Comment: It is a theorem I found in some real analysis notes, but their proof of the statement in the unbounded function case is wrong. I was trying to prove it myself but I wasn't able, so I came up with the doubt that it could be not true.

Comment: Would you mind editing your question to outline the incorrect proof, explaining why it's wrong? By the way, I think this statement _is_ true, and I can prove it. (That said, I'm very rusty with the Riemann integral. My proof would use Lebesgue integral techniques.)

Comment: I tried to explain the problem. I am not familiar with Lebesgue integral, and these notes only deal with Riemann integral, so I was hoping for a Riemann-only proof (or counterexample).